# Can not launch jar Spark with command spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, talend

I try to launch a jar Spark with a tSystem Component TALEND but I have a error :

Command tSystem :

```
"cmd /c spark-submit --class reprisesComptesExistants.PhasePreliminaire.main --master local[5] C:/Users/A661758/dataintegrationRepriseExistant/target/scala-2.11/dataintegrationRepriseExistant-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

Error :

```
Warning: Skip remote jar C:/Users/A661758/dataintegrationRepriseExistant/target/scala-2.11/dataintegrationRepriseExistant-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: reprisesComptesExistants.PhasePreliminaire
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:695)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
[statistics] disconnected
Job test1 terminé à 13:54 16/06/2017. [Code sortie=0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> local: - a URI starting with local:/ is expected to exist as a local
>   file on each worker node. This means that no network IO will be
>   incurred, and works well for large files/JARs that are pushed to each
>   worker, or shared via NFS, GlusterFS, etc.

Try to add `local:/` before the file uri like this :

```
local:/C:/Users/A661758/dataintegrationRepriseExistant/target/scala-2.11/dataintegrationRepriseExistant-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Or to get rid of windows fs path issues, just put your jar in the HDFS and use this synthax :

```
hdfs://hostname:9000/path/dataintegrationRepriseExistant-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Please be make sure you are mapping class name correclty.
It should be package.classname like com.company.test.Classname.
"com.company.test" is your package and Classname is your class.

If you are using talend bigdata platform V6.2.1, I recommend you to use bigdata batch job with spark instead of standarad job.